# Git commit and move with autosquash - like git commit --fixup (but without the squashing)

Tags: git

I like to use the `git commit --fixup` and then later do `git rebase -i --autosquash`. But sometimes I have some a work in progress commit (WIP) and would like to do a commit before that.

```
 -  some atomic commit
 -  WIP commit
(would like "some atomic commit" to be here)
 - some really cool commit
```

Can I do a one-line commit that also states if it should be moved before or after another commit when doing some rebase?

Comment: No. You have to rember to rearrange the commits in the todo-sheet manually. If you like, you can insert a reminder in the title during commit time, and then after rearranging the commit in the todo sheet, change the `pick` to `reword`; that gives you the opportunity to remove the reminder from the commit title.

Comment: …Or use `--autosquash` and change `fixup` to `pick`.